# Is there any hotkey to delete the command tips quickly in texstudio?

Tags: texstudio

`Texstudio` has the nice feature that when I type some build in command,  tips will come up. e.g. when I type `\frac`, the following will appear:

```
\frac{num}{den}
```

It is helpful because I do not need to type the two `{}`. But is there any quick way to delete `num` and `den` quickly? I found I need to delete the `den` in order to type my denominator.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `Ctrl`+`right` in order to alter these placeholders.

I have changed this shortcut to `Ctrl`+`space` for more easiness.